# Edit the html file directly with Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let me explain what I'm trying to do here.

So I have an html file that I want to update the content of the file directly. For example i have elements with the same 'id=test'. What I want is to update all the elements with 'id=test1', 'id=test2' dynamically not just in runtime but I want to edit the file itself. Is there a way to update the file directly with Jquery or Javascript?

Thank you for anyone that can help me.

Comment: You cannot modify the source code with javascript or with any of its libraries  but if you want to see the modified output you can use any server side scripting languages like php

Comment: @AluanHaddad how is it a security vulnerability ?

Comment: I was thinking of script injection but that can happen anyway.

Comment: @bharath I see. So can I edit the source code directly with php?

Comment: @ZyxSun You can't edit source code but you can acheive dynamic id's like test1 , test2 with php

Comment: Why does `html` contain duplicate `id`? What is expected result of editing file content?

Comment: Perhaps you should look into using a Content Management System.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you really want to happen but I think `$(element).html(html lines here)` could help you with that.

Comment: How will this update the file on the server? Javascript just runs locally to the client.

Comment: Oh sorry, you mean you want to rewrite a file itself. I don't have ideas on it but I'm pretty sure you need fwrite() of php (Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php).as a way to rewrite.